# Index a Multi Dimensional List with Single Known but Unique Value

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional list

```
multiDemList = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
```

I want to find the position of the list element `[3,'c']` by indexing the list for 3.

I've made various attempts at a wildcard

```
multiDemList.index([3,*])
```

Which illustrates by desired outcome...but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The following list comprehension will give you a list of all the indexes of lists in `multiDemList` whose first element is `3`:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(multiDemList) if v[0] == 3]
```

If you know that there'll only be one such element, you can use `next()` as in Avinash Raj's solution:

```
next(i for i, v in enumerate(multiDemList) if v[0] == 3)
```

Comment: `next` was what i wanted to add  on my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` within a function as following :

```
>>> multiDemList = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
>>> def return_indx(li):
...   for i,j in enumerate(li):
...      if j[0]==3:
...        return i
...   return None
... 
>>> return_indx(multiDemList)
2
```

Or:

```
>>> def return_indx(li,val):
...   try :
...      return next(i for i, j in enumerate(multiDemList) if j[0] == val)
...   except StopIteration :
...      return None
... 
>>> return_indx(multiDemList,3)
2
>>> return_indx(multiDemList,1)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this,

```
>>> multiDemList = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
>>> next(multiDemList.index([i[0],i[1]]) for i in multiDemList if i[0]==3)
2
```